# $A \in {M_n}$ is normal.why the range of $A$ and ${A^*}$ are the same?.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in {M_n}$ be normal. Why the range of $A$ and ${A^*}$ are the same?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the standard decomposition
$$
\mathbb{C}^n=C(A^*)\oplus N(A)
$$
where $C(B)$ and $N(B)$ (where $B$ is any matrix) denote respectively the column space (or range) and null space (or kernel).

Let $v\in \mathbb{C}^n$. Then we can uniquely write $v=x+z$, with $x\in C(A^*)$ and $z\in N(A)$. Thus $x=A^*y$ for some $y$, so
$$
Av=A(x+z)=Ax+Az=Ax=AA^*y=A^*Ay\in C(A^*)
$$
This means that $C(A)\subseteq C(A^*)$.

The converse follows by symmetry using $\mathbb{C}^n=C(A)\oplus N(A^*)$.