# $A \in {M_n}$ is normal.why the null space of $A$ is orthogonal to the range of $A$?.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A \in {M_n}$ is normal.why the null space of $A$ is orthogonal to the range of $A$?

Comment: What is the purpose of $B$ in this question?

Comment: For any matrix $A$, the null space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the column space of $A^*$ (Hermitian transpose). If $A$ is normal, the columns space of $A$ is the same as the column space of $A^*$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247383/a-b-in-m-n-are-normal-why-the-range-of-a-and-a-are-the-same/1247395#1247395

Answer (score 2):

For any matrix $A$, the null space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the column space of $A^*$ (Hermitian transpose). This is a basic fact about matrices.

If $A$ is normal, the columns space of $A$ is the same as the column space of $A^*$. See [$A \in {M_n}$ is normal.why the range of $A$ and ${A^*}$ are the same?.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247383/a-in-m-n-is-normal-why-the-range-of-a-and-a-are-the-same)